# file listing: difference between ls and echo *

Tags: linux, bash, ls, echo

on a lustre file system with thousands of file in directories, each time I type `ls` I get a large delay until files are listed. Same happens with other commands that need file listing. But if I type `echo *` I quickly get the name of the files.

What is the mechanism / internal difference how `ls` and similar commands access the filesystem, compared to `echo *`? what is happening underneath?

Comment: Is your `ls` an alias to something that shows file type indicators or coloured output for permissions, etc.? Then it might be `stat`ing all those files instead of just listing them.

Comment: no, `ls` is just the original command.

Comment: Then as a first step, I'd suggesting running `strace ls` to see what's taking so long.

Comment: Also did you run echo immediately after ls? In that case it's the caching effect

Comment: IIRC on very old discussion: `echo *` just open the directory and get the filenames. `ls` instead check also every entry. I think just to keep common code (e.g. to sort by date, or size, or to have coloured name according permissions)

Comment: I'm thinking `stat` happening too - bash and ls have to do the same queries to find filenames. So - you're saying there's no colored outputs from ls, right? How about running as "/bin/ls" - is that slow too?

Answer (score 2):

`ls` takes effort to list columns of file names neatly. It also needs information to know how to present the names (coloured or otherwise indicated for different file types), and potentially with details of the metadata associated with each directory entry. Here is an example from my Cygwin installation:

```
cd /bin
ls
[.exe                 cygpstoedit-0.dll       mpost.exe
__pycache__           cygptexenc-1.dll        msgtool.exe
a2ping                cygraqm-0.dll           msxlint.exe
a5toa4                cygraw_r-16.dll         mv.exe
acyclic.exe           cygraw-16.dll           named-rrchecker.exe
addftinfo.exe         cygreadline7.dll        namei.exe
...
```

Not directly relevant, but as you experiment with `ls` you will see that the column width will vary depending on the length of the longest filename. This requires that `ls` read and consider every filename before starting to output any. Newer versions of `ls` may also display "strange" file names and those containing spaces inside single quotes. (Personally, I have this disabled by setting `QUOTING_STYLE=literal`.)

`echo` does nothing clever by itself, but the shell will expand the `*` to be an alphanumerically sorted list of filenames and pass that list directly as words to `echo`. Here is that same directory, presented with `echo`:

```
cd /bin
echo *
[.exe __pycache__ a2ping a5toa4 acyclic.exe addftinfo.exe addr2line.exe adhocfilelist afm2pl.exe afm2tfm.exe aleph.exe allcm allec allneeded animate apropos ar.exe arara arch.exe arlatex as.exe ascii.exe ash.exe autosp.exe awk axohelp.exe b2sum.exe banner.exe base32.exe...
```

What you are seeing is that the shell's extraction of a list of filenames is significantly faster than the processing performed by `ls` to create a neat list. GNU `ls` allows you to disable the display processing with `ls -f`. (See `man ls` for what it actually does.)

Answer (score -1):

The current shell is going to replace `*` with a list of files (assumption read from `.`file) separated with spaces, before executing `echo` command.

`echo` will handle each sequence of chars between spaces as word and output the list of words separated with space char. Meaning that multiple spaces will be handle has only one: a separator of word. So, the exact name of files might be changed in the output: when there are space or special chars in the files' names.

`ls` is accessing the `.` file, which is a file containing the list of files in the current directory and prints the filenames separated with `<new line>` char.

Comment: and how does this explain the difference in time it takes?

Comment: ```strace ls``` : there are some extra ```stat``` and ```lstat``` and it reads system files as well. Maybe this is why?

Comment: maybe they are. But you didn't mention them in this answer here. Instead, the answer seems to say the two commands do the exact same thing.

Comment: I try to explain the differences between the ```echo *``` and the ```ls```. For example the ```echo *``` can mess up the filename whereas the ```ls``` won't. This is a difference, and it is explained in the answer.